# Remain the selection in a list

Tags: extjs

I have these two guys who change the list order

[buttons and selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKDQU.png)

But when a position is changed, I lose focus on selection

[new order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL3T0.png)

I need that when this change happens that the selection remains on the item.

This is the code for the buttons.

```
{
    xtype: 'use-icon',
    clsIcone: 'x-mi mi-keyboard-arrow-up font-size-20 cursor-pointer',
    toolTipText: 'Subir etapa',
    reference: 'btnSubirEtapa',
    cbOnClick: 'onClickSubirEtapa'
}, {
    xtype: 'use-icon',
    clsIcone: 'x-mi mi-keyboard-arrow-down font-size-20 cursor-pointer',
    toolTipText: 'Descer etapa',
    reference: 'btnDescerEtapa',
    cbOnClick: 'onClickDescerEtapa'
}
```

and here the controller

```
    onClickSubirEtapa: function() {
    var me = this,
        $vw = me.getView(),
        $grid = $vw.down('fichatecnica-sequenciaoperacional-operacoes-window-lista'),
        selection = $grid.getSelection();

    if($grid.getController().validarSelecao(selection, 1, 1)) {
        me.subirOperacao(selection[0]);
    }
},

subirOperacao:function(record) {
    var me = this,
        vwm = me.getViewModel(),
        modelFichaTecnica = vwm.get('FichaTecnica'),
        codigoFichaTecnica = vwm.get('CodigoFichaTecnica'),
        rep = me.getRepositorio();

    rep.subirOperacao(codigoFichaTecnica, vwm.get('CodigoEtapa'), record.data.Id, Use.Callback.padrao(function() {
        me.recuperarOperacoes(codigoFichaTecnica);
    }));
},
```

if further details are needed, I can add.

Edit. Ext Version: 6.5.3.
Toolkit Classic.

Comment: Which version of extjs are you using? Which toolkit: classic or modern?

Comment: Are you using server-side ordering?

Comment: Version 6.5.3. Yes, I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in store reload. After server side ordering the store is loaded with new data and grid resets the selection. In this case you must store the selected recordId (I hope you are using server side record ids) and after load of the store reselect the rows by record ids.

Something like the following fiddle sample:

```
Ext.define('SampleGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: {
        fields: ['fieldOne', 'fieldTwo'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'root'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    },
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            text: "Reload",
            handler: function () {
                var grid = this.up('grid'),
                    store = grid.getStore();
                store.load();
            }
        }]
    }],
    columns: [{
        text: 'Field One',
        dataIndex: 'fieldOne',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Field Two',
        dataIndex: 'fieldTwo',
        flex: 1
    }],

    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent();
        this.addRememberSelectionFeature();
    },

    addRememberSelectionFeature: function () {
        // Store record id on select
        this.on('select', function (grid, selectedRecord) {
            this.storedSelectedRecordId = selectedRecord.getId();
        }, this);

        // Select records after reload
        this.getStore().on('load', function (store) {
            var lastSelectedRecord = store.getById (this.storedSelectedRecordId);
            if (lastSelectedRecord) {
                this.getSelectionModel().select(this.storedSelectedRecords);
            }
        }, this);
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('SampleGrid', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

The data with server side ids (not autogenerated by extjs):

```
{
    "root": [{
        "id": 0,
        "fieldOne": 1,
        "fieldTwo": 4
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "fieldOne": 2,
        "fieldTwo": 3
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "fieldOne": 3,
        "fieldTwo": 2
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "fieldOne": 4,
        "fieldTwo": 1
    }]
}
```

In must change the code if you are using multiple selection model, just keep the ids of selected records in an array.